# error NameError: name 'head' is not defined on jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

i am trying to  import a dataset in jupyter notebook and i wrote the following code following a tutorial i was following on youtube but i couldn't run the dataset. here is the code;

```
df = pandas.read_csv('C:\\Users\\CMuasya\\downloads\\data_wrangling_datasets\\data\\gapminder.tsv', sep='\t')
df = head()
```

the error being displayed is as follows;

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> ----> 1 df = head()
>
> NameError: name 'head' is not defined

what could be the problem and what is the solution to the error? kind regards

Comment: `df = df.head()`

Comment: The problem is that head() is undefined within the scope. The solution depends on the steps you were supposed to follow in order to get here, likely a missed import. Please post a link to the video so that prospective answerers know what you're trying to do.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iYie42M1ZyU

Answer (score 2):

individual head() is nothing if you want get 5 rows of data then

```
df = pd.read_csv('xyz.csv')
print(df.head())
```

head is a method called on dataframe